# How can i call a code behind function when user clicks a gridview row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I have a gridview in an aspx page with c# code behind.

Is there a way how i can run a code behind function when the user clicks anywhere on a row? For now, i use the select button. But then the user has to click on that button. And i want to user to be able to click anywhere on a row to show it's details in another gridview that is located next to the main gridview.

Some ideas here on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Link" Visible="false" SelectText="Enroll" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(a => new
            {
                ID = a,
                FirstName = String.Format("First {0}", a),
                LastName = String.Format("Last{0}", a)
            });
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Bind other grid

        Response.Write(GridView1.SelectedIndex+1);

    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //add css to GridViewrow based on rowState
            e.Row.CssClass = e.Row.RowState.ToString();
            //Add onclick attribute to select row.
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Select${0}')", e.Row.RowIndex));
        }
    }
```